# Form not connected ReactJs, even though only one button in form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am trying to create a form to add a new item into an array, but I am getting the error: `Form submission cancelled because form is not connected`. I found some posts saying that replacing the submit button type with "button" instead of "submit" but its not working.
My code is below:

```
import React, { useState,useContext } from 'react';
import { ItemContext } from "../ItemsContext.js";

const AddExpense = ( )=> {
    const [items,setItems] = useContext(ItemContext)
    const [name,setName] = useState()
    const [price,setPrice] = useState()
    const handleSubmit = ()=>{
        const newItem = {title:name,price:price}
        const newList = items.budgetItems.pop(newItem)
        setItems({budget:items.budget, budgetItems:newList})

    }
    const handleNameChange=(event)=>{
        setName(event.target.value)
    }
    const handlePriceChange= (event)=>{
        setPrice(event.target.value)
    }
    return (
        <div onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <form >
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" onChange={handleNameChange} />
                <label htmlFor="price">Price</label>
                <input type="number" id="price" onChange={handlePriceChange}/>
                <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
            </form>

        </div>
    )
}
export default AddExpense
```

Display expenses code:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Expense from './expenses.js'
import { ItemContext } from "../ItemsContext.js";

const ExpenseDisplay =()=> {
    const [items, setItems] = useContext(ItemContext)
    let stuff = items.budgetItems
    return (
        <div>
            {stuff.map((items)=><Expense key={items.id} items={items}/>)}
        </div>
    )
}
export default ExpenseDisplay;
```

Expense Component:

```
import React, { useContext,useState} from 'react';
import { ItemContext } from "../ItemsContext.js";

const Expense =({items})=> {
    const [expense, setExpense] = useContext(ItemContext)
    let stuff = expense.budgetItems

    const handleRemove =()=> {
        const newExpense = stuff.filter(itemChecked=>itemChecked.id!==items.id)
        
        setExpense({budget:expense.budget, budgetItems:newExpense});
    }
    return (
        <div className="expense">
            <h3>{items.title}</h3>
            <h3>{items.price}</h3>
            <button onClick={handleRemove}>X</button>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Expense;
```

[image]

Edit: One answer suggested to move the onSubmit into the form element, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Error says that stuff is undefined It is better to check if stuff is not empty then map through it.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Expense from './expenses.js'
import { ItemContext } from "../ItemsContext.js";

const ExpenseDisplay =()=> {
  const [items, setItems] = useContext(ItemContext)
   let stuff = items.budgetItems
    if(stuff && stuff.length > 0){
    return (
       <div>
        {stuff.map((items)=><Expense key={items.id} items={items}/>)}
      </div>
    )
  }else{
    return (
     <p>There is no item in stuff.</p>
   )
 }
}
export default ExpenseDisplay;
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error, ill attach a pic of the console

Comment: check the updated question

Comment: and also store the context like this
    `const items = useContext(ItemContext)`

Comment: the displaying is working, however the adding is not working still. There are no errors, but it just reloads and nothing is added

Comment: put `onSubmit` IN form tag and also inside `const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
     .........
    } `
and also console.log each step.

Answer (score 0):

Add `onSubmit` to the `form` element

Change this

```
return (
        <div onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <form >
               ...
               ...
            </form>

        </div>
    )
```

to

```
return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
               ...
               ...
            </form>

        </div>
    )
```